# Failed to start Apache Tomcat from netbeans macOSX (Problem 1: deployment error: starting of Tomcat failed, Problem 2: port 8080 already in use)

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

> ```
> This is how it worked for me.
> 1) Go to **/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/conf**
>
> In the server.xml file, in the Connector element for HTTP/1.1, add the following attribute: server="Apache-Coyote/1.1".
>
> Example:
>
> <Connector
>   connectionTimeout="20000"
>   port="8080"
>   protocol="HTTP/1.1"
>   redirectPort="8443"
>   server="Apache-Coyote/1.1"
> />
>
> 2) Go to netbeans8.2 . app -> right click show package contents ->contents->resources->netbeans->enterprise->modules->
>
> then you can find and replace the file ("org-netbeans-modules-tomcat5.jar") with "https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12994224/org-netbeans-modules-tomcat5.jar"
> ```
>
> https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12994224/org-netbeans-modules-tomcat5.jar

Answer (score 1):

kill the process after searching the process id
`ps -ef|grep tomcat`
then
`kill -9 <processid>`

Then start tomcat again.

Comment: The issue is of netbeans. Apache tomact server starts normally with ./catalina.sh start command but from netbeans its not starting